# PostgreSQL : User access restriction based on field value

Tags: postgresql

We have a DB view that has many tables having "location" field common in most tables, requirement is we need to provide restricted access to users based on location field, e.g. a US user can see/query only data that has location as US.
how we can create such user in DB with this restricted access?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I would normally implement this kind of restrictions in my client business logic. For your case I would recommend you to check the documentation available here:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html
(I did not use this yet)

Answer (score 0):

If you can uniquely identify the location for each user, then you can create Views over your base Tables and join these to your "users" table by location (and filter by current user id):

```
create table table1
( ... 
/* lots of other stuff */ 
, ...
, location int 
, ... 
); 

create table app_users
( id int 
, location int 
, ... 
, index( id, location ) 
); 

create view table1v as 
  select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, ... 
  from table1 t1 
  inner join app_users u 
        on t1.location = u.location 
       and u.id = CURRENT_USER_ID
```

The "fun" part is working out who to get hold of the current user id *inside* the database!  If, as I do, you use a dedicated, shared, Application account to get into the database (as opposed to individual database accounts for [each and] every User - IMHO, a maintenance nightmare) then you'll have to somehow "pass" this information from the Application *to* the database - possibly in some some sort of "variable" set before running any Query, or possibly as part of each [and every] Query.
Of course, your actual User Id (the meaningless, numerical value that represents a User account) *shouldn't* "leak" outside of your database (into the Application layer) but this might be one case where you just *have* to.